exams2moodle: Radio buttons for single-choice options in cloze questions
When generating cloze questions for Moodle with exams2moodle(), the single-choice subquestions appear as dropdown lists rather than with radio buttons. The issue with this is that the whole text isn't visible in this view for sufficiently long answer options, meaning students wouldn't be able to see the whole option before deciding whether to select it. See Q3 in the screenshot below for an example.  
Would it be possible if schoice questions could be imported into Moodle as "MULTICHOICE_V" rather than the current "MULTICHOICE" subquestions within the cloze (see here), so that the options appear in radio button rather than dropdown view, and that the entire text within long answer options is visible?
Note that I can see how to ensure the options appear in radio view by writing the answer field text verbatim, but this would be more work than one would desire to do :)

You can select the display type for single-choice interactions in cloze questions via cloze_schoice_display, e.g., as in
exams2moodle(..., cloze = list(cloze_schoice_display = "MULTICHOICE_V"))


Thanks Achim. Apologies, I should have been aware of this!

No worries! Might be helpful for others as well...
